# Which of the following functions $f : \mathbb{R^2} → \mathbb{R^2}$ is a linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra

Which of the following functions $f : \mathbb{R^2} → \mathbb{R^2}$ is a linear transformation?

[image]

So I've cross out b and d since they do not work with the zero vector. But both a and c look like they work under addition and scalar multiplication. I would go with a but I would like to hear other opinions.

Comment: are you sure $c$ behaves properly??

Comment: hmmmm, not entirely certain, why would you think that?

Comment: Does $x_1+1 + x_2+1 = (x_1+x_2)+1$?

Comment: a+1 + c+1 = x+1 and
b+1 + d+1 = y+1

I made those equations and checked for conflicts, am I doing it wrong?

Comment: I still dont quite understand why c does not work under addition

Comment: Two abritary vectors added together equals another vector in that space

Comment: @AA, do you know that a linear function maps zero to zero? Well, there goes (c)....

Comment: uhhh, I don't quite understand what you mean.............. This is confusing

Comment: Why are you concerned with zero mapping to zero?

Comment: What do you mean by "d does not work with the zero vector"?

Comment: @AA Zero must map to zero because $f(V) = f(V+\vec{0}) = f(V)+f(\vec{0})$, implying that $f(\vec{0})=\vec{0}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function (c) is called affine. An affine subspace doesn't preserve addition. So if I took: $T(1, 1) + T(1, 1) = (2, 2) + (2, 2) \neq T(2, 2) = (3, 3)$.

So in order to preserve addition, the zero vector must map to the zero vector. Consider $T(0, 0) + T(0, 0) = T(0, 0)$. If there is any sort of affine offset like in (c), you get $2T(0, 0) \neq T(0, 0)$ (as adding $(0, 0) + (0, 0) = (0, 0))$. So addition is not preserved.

Function (a) is the only one that behaves correctly.